# Using reflection to determine assembly module type

Tags: .net, reflection, .net-assembly

How would one use .net reflection to determine the type of the executing assembly, by type I mean dll or exe. Currently its possible to do something like:

`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase.ToLower.EndsWith(".exe")`

But it seems like something better could exist that does not need to do a string comparison, i.e. comparing the assemblies module name would also fall into this category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure about that, but I think that `Assembly.EntryPoint` is null for DLLs.